# Problema datos entre form (html) JS y php con AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

me he pasado el día dándole vueltas y sigo sin ver que hago mal. Por favor si alguien me puede dar una manito.

Llego a leer el valor del input que envia el formulario al archivo JS. Cuando intento pasar ese dato por AJAX al archivo PHP ya parece que no llega. Lo que más me confunde es que si le doy al formulario sin definir valor en la variable a enviar, entonces si que la llamada ajax se realiza y me pinta el error en donde debería pintar el resultado cuando envío una variable...

Les dejo el código, qué estaré haciendo mal???

HTML

```
 <form id="formulario2" class="form col-12 d-flex  p-0 justify-content-sm-around justify-content-center align-items-center ml-sm-3 mb-3" method="post" action="#" autocomplete="off">

                <div class=" col-12 col-sm-6  pl-sm-2 continputs m-3">

                    <input class="search_query col-12 resestret" type="text"  name="coopera" id="coopera" placeholder="¿Busca tu cooperativa aquí?" charset="ISO-8859-1" required>

                    <div id="autocoope" class="ml-2" style="display: none;"></div>
                    <div id="autocoopera"></div>
                </div>

                     <button type="submit" id='enviacoope'  class="btn btn-info align-self-start m-3 col-3">Buscar!</button> 
        </form>
```

JS

```
$('#enviacoope').on('click', function() {

    var  coopera = $('#coopera').val();        
    var dataString3 = 'dato='+coopera;

   //alert(coopera);

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actioncooperativas.php",
        data: dataString3,
        success: function(data) { 

            $('#infocoope').fadeIn(1000).html(data);

            //alert("lo hizo!");

            return false;

        }
    });
});
```

PHP

```
$cooperativa2=$_POST['dato']; 

echo $cooperativa2;
```

Os agradcería mucho alguna ayuda!!

No puse más del código php para no agobiar, pero pego un poco más por si puede aclarar.

```
require ("datos_bbdd.php");


$cooperativa2=$_POST['dato']; 

echo $cooperativa2; 

date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");


$conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);


$resulcoopera2 = array();


      if (is_null($cooperativa2)) {

            echo "se lo ha saltado";

        }else{
                echo "lo ha hecho";
                
           $consulta_cooperativa="SELECT * FROM companias_busca";

           $taulacooperatives=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_cooperativa);

        }

$x=0;
$z=0;
```

while(($cooperativas=mysqli_fetch_array($taulacooperatives,MYSQLI_BOTH))){

Cuando envio el formulario con la variable a recoger vacía, es cuando hace la llamada y me da el error el llegar al mysqli_fetch_array. Como puede ser que haga la llamada con la variabla vacia, y no cuando la variable lleva algun valor?

[image: Error en pantalla]

He insertado en código verificador de errores gentileza de @Triby y aún no puedo ver que es lo que falla.

He especificado y hecho la consulta SQL en phpmyadmin. Se ejecuta bien. cabe decir que ya hago una consulta ajax sobre esta misma tabla para llenar el input con autocompletado.
[image: Verificacición Consulta SQL]

Ejecutando la AJAX pasándole el mismo dato que el ejemplo SQL ("Alausí") da error. El dato que se capta en el script con la variable coopera se puede leer con un alert, pero no se llega a ejecutar la acción.
[image: Alert del script leyendo la variable a eniar por ajax, Coopera]

[image: Error producido en AJAX]

Pago aquí también como ha quedado el php, con la modificación de la consulta SQL

```
 $salida = ['error' => true, 'mensaje' => 'Dato proporcionado es inválido'];
    // Asegura que tienes un valor adecuado con asignación ternaria
    $cooperativa2 = (isset($_POST['dato'])) ? trim($_POST['dato']) : ''; 
    //echo $cooperativa2 . "Facuuuuuuu";

if($cooperativa2 != '') {
    // Sí hay un valor
    $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
    // Tu consulta debería tener un filtro
    $consulta_cooperativa=    'SELECT * FROM companias_busca WHERE Cooperativa LIKE "'.$cooperativa2.'"';
    $taulacooperatives=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_cooperativa);
    
    if($taulacooperatives === false) {

        $salida['mensaje'] = 'Error ejecutando consulta';

    } elseif(mysqli_num_rows($taulacooperatives) == 0) {

        // La consulta se ejecutó, pero no hay resultados
        $salida['error'] = false;
        $salida['mensaje'] = 'No hay resultados para mostrar';

    } else {

        // La consulta se ejecutó y hay resultados
        $salida['error'] = false;
        while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($taulacooperatives)) {
            // Cambia $datos[X] por las columnas que desees mostrar
            $salida['mensaje'] .= "<p>Información: {$datos[0]}, {$datos[1]}</p>";
        }
}
}
// Finalmente, envías el resultado como JSON:
echo json_encode($salida);
```

No consigo ver que es lo que va mal, El error que salta no estoy seguro si se debe a que el json se genera con valores nulos, o que llega vacío... Un poco más de ayuda??

Un saludo.

Finalmente probé una vez más las recomendaciones de @Tribi y estuve probando el php aislado con GET, funcionó, pero al integrar la llamada AJAX de nuevo no se realizaba la acción... rehize los archivos dejandolos de la siguiente manera:

PHP

```
$dato = $_POST['dato'];

$taulacooperatives2 = $connexion->query(

    'SELECT * FROM companias'

);

$z=0;
```

while(($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($taulacooperatives2,MYSQLI_BOTH))){

JS

```
$('#formulario2').on('submit', function(e) {

   e.preventDefault();

  let  coopera = $('#coopera').val().trim();

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "probandoconsulta.php",
        data: {dato:coopera},

        // El resultado devuelto por PHP será interpretado como JSON
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {

            $('#infocoope').fadeIn(1000).html(data);

            $('#butpoli2').on('click', function(data){  

                $('#infocoope').fadeOut(8000).html(data);

            });

        },
        // Captura cualquier posible error
        error: function(ajax, estado, texto) {
            alert('Hubo un error en AJAX: ' + texto);
        }
    });
});
```

Finalmente no he descubierto porque no funcionaba la duda expuesta, pero igual agradeczco mucho las ayudas y corroboro que he aprendido cosas interesantes.

saludos,

Comment: Gracias Triby por el comentario. Ya puse el data: {dato: $('#coopera').val()}, y sigue sin realizar la llamada.

Comment: Gracias de nuevo @Triby. Pero mi problema, por ahora no es con el PHP, que ya lo solucionaré. El problema es que la llamada ajax solo la hace si envio el formulario vacio, si le envio algún valor de los que genera el input, aunque puedo leerlos con alert antes de meterlos en la llamada ajax, esta llamada no se ejecuta... Podría ser que la variable que genera el input esté en algun formato que se puede leer en alert pero no la reconoce para enviarla por ajax?? ;( estoy desesperando poco a poco...

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para poner tu código actualizado y el mensaje de error que te aparece.

Comment: Prueba abriendo directamente el script desde `localhost/ruta/actioncooperativas.php?dato=aulasi` y, por el momento, cambia en PHP `$_POST['dato']` por `$_GET['dato']`; no lo integres en AJAX hasta que funcione correctamente de esta forma.

Comment: Hola de nuevo @triby. Hice como me dijistes y conseguí hacr la consulta desde el php, pero la ajax luego seguia dando el mismo error... ya me cansé tras dos días de intentos y rehice los dos archivos cambiando un poco la gramática php, finalmente ha funcionado, ya lo pongo en la pregunta. En cualquier caso muchísimas gracias por tus comentarios, me han enseñado bastantes cosas qu eme servirán a futuro.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de asignar el evento al botón, hazlo con el formulario para que puedas evitar el comportamiento normal (ir a otra página o recargar la actual):

```
$('#formulario2').on('submit', function(e) {
   // Evita el comportamiento normal del formulario
   e.preventDefault();
   // Usa trim() para eliminar espacios al inicio o final
   let  coopera = $('#coopera').val().trim();
   //alert(coopera);
   // Haz alguna validación, por ejemplo, que sean mínimo 3 caracteres
   if(coopera.length < 3) {
       alert('Teclea al menos 3 caracteres');
       return;
   }

   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "actioncooperativas.php",
        // Envía los datos como objeto: 'variable' => 'valor'
        data: {dato:coopera},
        // El resultado devuelto por PHP será interpretado como JSON
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.error) {
                alert('Sí lo hizo, pero hubo error: ' + data.mensaje);
            } else {
                $('#infocoope').fadeIn(1000).html(data.mensaje);
                alert('Sí lo hizo');
            }
        },
        // Captura cualquier posible error
        error: function(ajax, estado, texto) {
            alert('Hubo un error en AJAX: ' + texto);
        }
    });
});
```

Luego, en PHP, asegúrate de recibir correctamente el valor antes de intentar cualquier otra cosa y, la salida, siempre debe ser un JSON válido:

```
require ("datos_bbdd.php");
date_default_timezone_set("America/Bogota");

// Crea una variable para almacenar la salida
$salida = ['error' => true, 'mensaje' => 'Dato proporcionado es inválido'];

// Asegura que tienes un valor adecuado con asignación ternaria
$cooperativa2 = (isset($_POST['dato'])) ? trim($_POST['dato']) : ''; 
if($cooperativa2 != '') {
    // Sí hay un valor
    $conexion=mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_usuario,$db_contra);
    // Tu consulta debería tener un filtro
    $consulta_cooperativa="SELECT * FROM companias_busca";
    $taulacooperatives=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_cooperativa);
    if($taulacooperatives === false) {
        $salida['mensaje'] = 'Error ejecutando consulta';
    } elseif(mysqli_num_rows($taulacooperatives) == 0) {
        // La consulta se ejecutó, pero no hay resultados
        $salida['error'] = false;
        $salida['mensaje'] = 'No hay resultados para mostrar';
    } else {
        // La consulta se ejecutó y hay resultados
        $salida['error'] = false;
        while($datos = mysqli_fetch_array($taulacooperatives)) {
            // Cambia $datos[X] por las columnas que desees mostrar
            $salida['mensaje'] .= "<p>Información: {$datos[0]}, {$datos[1]}</p>";
        }
    }
}
// Finalmente, envías el resultado como JSON:
echo json_encode($salida);
```

Con estos sencillos pasos, estás cubriendo cualquier posibilidad de error, tanto en Javascript, como en PHP y tendrás una pista de lo que debes corregir porque siempre verás de qué se trata el error.

Comment: Hola de nuevo. Intenté ponem más datos subre tu respuesta @triby, pero no se porque aun no se ve. Te agradecía de nuevo y te contaba que integré tu código y me da error  cuando se ejecuta la ajax, salta esto: Hubo un error en AJAX: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data      Te ponía también una imagen donde se veia el error y tambien me di cuenta que no explique que el input del formulario se llena seleccionando una opción de las que muestro ejecutando otra llamada ajax que sí funciona. Con el error que sale, por donde podría seguir buscando??

Comment: No aparecen porque rechacé la edición, no debes modificar la respuesta, sino tu pregunta. Y creo que el problema sigue siendo con la consulta, ¿ya la probaste en PhpMyAdmin? ¿Verificaste que la tabla existe?

Comment: Ahh, perdona @Triby, aún estoy aprendiendo como funciona el foro. Gracias y ya mismo modifico mi pregunta